# Why do we need space and subspace in linear algebra?

Tags: linear-algebra

Why we don't call subspaces just spaces? sometimes my professor says "Given subspace V" but I don't get why he doesn't say "space". 
What is the difference between them?

Comment: He is probably trying to emphasize the fact that it is a subset of some bigger space. For instance, you could talk about $\mathbb{R}$ being its own space, if thats all you care about, or you could talk about it being a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$ to illustrate some other point about this subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$

Comment: Your question is vague unless you give one or more specific examples. Most times, we call something a subspace if it is important that the space is included in another space in a particular way.

Comment: A subspace is a vector space that's also a subset of some vector space.  There's no really difference between them in practice though.  Every vector space is in fact a subspace (though often only trivially so).

Comment: Well, it's more than that, @Bye_World. It's a vector space which is a subset of another vector space, *and* has the same field of scalars, and the operations $+$ and $\cdot$ agree.

Comment: @LiziPizi it would be helpful if you could give us a specific example of a context in which your professor said that.

Answer (score 1):

To difference them is important. For example, someone ask you find a max value in a space. Some other may put a constraint so it becomes to find  a max value in a subspace. The two max values are different. Constraints are translated to subspace in math.

Comment: What do you mean by "max value in space"?

Comment: if you have a function with its variables in a domain. Max value is the function maximum and domain is "space".

Comment: I still don't get it sorry... function maximum?

Comment: or maximum value of the function.

Comment: but how can there be a max value if the function goes from infinite set to infinite set?